# Using Poly Wav files in Logic Studio 9

Tags: poly-wav, logic, pro-tools, bwf, 192khz

So I just mirrored 9 gigs of poly wav files (6 - 8 channel BWFs) from my Deva in 192k.  I'm not running PTHD at home, so I can't run PT in 192k at home.

I can run Logic at home at 192k, but for some reason Logic doesn't like my poly wavs.  I've had this problem before, but I've never had to deal with it at 192k.  Logic is interpreting my files as surround files, so it brings all the channels into 1 track and assigns them to a surround panner.  Then it won't let me break them each out to separate channels.

Any ideas?  Anyone run into this problem in Logic?  How did you rectify it?

Comment: hope you get an answer soon! Nobody likes a forlorn question…

Comment: @Jay - apparently. I did a work around (suggested by Michael Rafael) where I split my poly files to mono with Wave Agent. Not a very pretty solution, but at least it gets me up and running for now...

Comment: I agree, the easiest way around it is to either export the files as mono files from PT or split them prior to importing into Logic. Whether the files are 5.1 or multiple channel layouts like yours. It's unfortunate but what can you do?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to bring in the wave on 5 different mono chanels?  That's my workaround when having similar problems in Pro-Tools.  My next idea would be to duplicate the tracks, and pan them as you see fit......if that's an option.

Comment: Logic won't let you split a poly to mono tracks easily. You have to export than re-import. Very stupid

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to hear if there's a real solution for this also. I remember when I first stumbled onto a multi-channel .wav file and I was like "how the hell does Logic handle these?" Short answer? It doesn't.

Comment: The only real solution I can find it to split to mono before I import. Lame.

Answer (score 1):

Logic and PT surround has channels ordered in a different way. Even if poly wavs contain the relevant metadata re channels (which frankly I doubt), the DAW is free to ignore that. Logic is exceptional at ignoring things it shouldn't.

Comment: Nah, all my Polywavs have channel layouts, track names, etc... in the Metadata.  Comes up beautifully in PT, Waveagent, Nuendo, etc...  Logic Seems to be the only "Pro" program out there that refuses to work for me. I find a new reason almost every day to stop using Logic.

Comment: Logic is great. If only it wasn't so ill-mannered at times. 

Answer (score 1):

Logic is geared more for music production than audio post production (although I use Logic for both). If you have the Logic studio bundle, then Soundtrack Pro will deal with poly wavs by splitting them onto individual tracks. From there you should be able to export to Logic.